# Append or Strip path to individual server in backend - HAProxy

Tags: haproxy

First, a thank you for taking the time

I would like to add/remove a path /somepath in the backend for just one server where there are two servers LB. Let me give you an example. In the below one server 10.0.0.10 accepts traffic with /somepath but the other server 10.0.0.20 doesn’t require the /somepath. If I use a reqrep and strip /somepath it would strip it for both servers, however, I would want it to be stripped/add to only one server in the backend. I am using Haproxy version 1.5.

```
mode http
balance roundrobin
server webtest1 10.0.0.10:80 weight 90
server webtest2 10.0.0.20:80 weight 10
```